# How can I use option (⌥) + mouse wheel to zoom the content in Keynote/Pages/Preview?

Tags: keyboard, catalina, mouse, preview, keynote

So, this is my struggle - lately, I've been using Apps such as Keynote / Pages / Preview.

From MS Word, other .pdf browser, I am used to the combination of `⌥ + mouse wheel`  (option + mouse wheel) to zoom in/out the content. However, default macOS Apps do no support this and it's been quite unpleasant while I work using external monitor most of the time.

Is there any solution?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using Command or CTRL? I seem to remember one of those used to zoom with a mouse wheel. I use a Magic TrackPad now, which offers much better control for scrolling and zooming than a mouse.

Comment: @benwiggy Unfortunately, none of these work - believe me, I tried almost any key combination as well as google a lot about this. As for the zooming sensitivity control - when I am able to use "option + mouse wheel" in other apps, I have to say that I get a pretty decent control of zooming (e.g., I can manage to zoom fast while drawing in Affinity - I would say almost equivalent to MacBook trackpad).

Comment: Do you at least get horizontal scrolling when you do Shift + wheel? What model of mouse is it?

Comment: @benwiggy Combination of Shift + wheel does not do anything. I can scroll horizontally just simply using a mouse wheel. If I tap "Shift", I cannot scroll...

Comment: What model of mouse is it? Some types require drivers to do advanced things or modify behaviour.

Comment: @benwiggy Logitech Pro Wireless. However, if any driver would be required, how come that I can zoom majority of other Apps?

Comment: Some third-party apps may have implemented that UI feature themselves. But if it isn't happening in Apple's own apps, then either MacOS doesn't provide that capability, or it does but your mouse can't access it. Logitec Control Centre software may provide the feature you're looking for.

Comment: @benwiggy Ye, you are probably right. As for the third party softwares, I would like to avoid them. Thanks anyway for all the tips.

Answer (score 1):

In Preview the closest functionality that resembles zooming with a key + scroll wheel I found is using the "Gesture button" of a Logitech MX Master.

I have this configured in Logi Options as a Preview specific setting:

[image]

In Preview I can now zoom in by holding the "Gesture button" and moving my mouse forward and zoom out by holding the same button and moving my mouse backward.

Definitely not the same as using a key + scroll, but it allows me to zoom without having to press a key combo on my keyboard.

There is a custom function in Logi Options that can be assigned to a mouse button which (temporarily) enables "Zoom using scroll wheel", but I found it unreliable and could not figure out how soon after pressing the configured button I should use the scroll wheel to zoom.

Comment: Thanks, looks like a solution, however, I am using a different mouse without any 3rd party software. It's been over two years since I asked question and regardless of the macOS updates and new iterations, nothing . And so many apps have this feature, not mentioning the MS Office.